# Regarding send SMS using Message media API (AEST number)

Tags: php, sms, messagemedia

The error is with the below line which returns a NULL value,
$body = MessageMediaMessagesLib\APIHelper::deserialize($bodyValue);

I have accept the SMS content in plain text area which contains 246 characters long and contain .

Message -
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an \ unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

it reruns the NULL result.
After POST the message I have trim the content -
    $Message = trim($Message);

What is the solution on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here had tried as per below and it worked for me,

```
$textContent="Your Message";
$textContent = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), '\n', $textContent);
$textContent = nl2br($textContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked to make sure that your $bodyValue is valid JSON? If so, can you also confirm that you have tried the sample code listed on the repository (https://github.com/messagemedia/messages-php-sdk) after installing it via composer?